# Vulkan does not work

Tags: nvidia, 17.10, vulkan

I have an AMD FX CPU
Nvidia GTX 650 ti
up to date ubuntu 17.10 with 384.90 nvidia drivers.

When I try to run Dawn of War III under Vulkan I get this error message:

ubuntu required Vulkan extension VK_KHR_surface is not available

`Vulkaninfo` outputs:

```
===========
VULKAN INFO
===========

Vulkan API Version: 1.0.61

INFO: [loader] Code 0 : Found manifest file /home/papajo/.local/share/vulkan/implicit_layer.d/steamoverlay_i386.json, version "1.0.0"
INFO: [loader] Code 0 : Found manifest file /home/papajo/.local/share/vulkan/implicit_layer.d/steamoverlay_x86_64.json, version "1.0.0"
INFO: [loader] Code 0 : Meta-layer VK_LAYER_LUNARG_standard_validation all 0 component layers appear to be valid.
INFO: [loader] Code 0 : Found ICD manifest file /usr/share/vulkan/icd.d/nvidia_icd.json, version "1.0.0"
ERROR: [loader] Code 0 : loader_scanned_icd_add: Attempt to retrieve either 'vkGetInstanceProcAddr' or 'vk_icdGetInstanceProcAddr' from ICD libGL.so.1 failed.
Cannot create Vulkan instance.
/build/vulkan-L06RNr/vulkan-1.0.61.1+dfsg1/demos/vulkaninfo.c:704: failed with VK_ERROR_INCOMPATIBLE_DRIVER
```

And `hwinfo --gfxcard` output is:

```
33: PCI 100.0: 0300 VGA compatible controller (VGA)             
  [Created at pci.378]
  Unique ID: VCu0.Q5LVSWQ7Z_D
  Parent ID: _Znp.+7g4VeAizS0
  SysFS ID: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/0000:01:00.0
  SysFS BusID: 0000:01:00.0
  Hardware Class: graphics card
  Model: "nVidia GK106 [GeForce GTX 650 Ti]"
  Vendor: pci 0x10de "nVidia Corporation"
  Device: pci 0x11c6 "GK106 [GeForce GTX 650 Ti]"
  SubVendor: pci 0x1569 "Palit Microsystems Inc."
  SubDevice: pci 0x11c6 
  Revision: 0xa1
  Driver: "nvidia"
  Driver Modules: "nvidia"
  Memory Range: 0xfd000000-0xfdffffff (rw,non-prefetchable)
  Memory Range: 0xf0000000-0xf7ffffff (ro,non-prefetchable)
  Memory Range: 0xf8000000-0xf9ffffff (ro,non-prefetchable)
  I/O Ports: 0xe000-0xe07f (rw)
  Memory Range: 0x000c0000-0x000dffff (rw,non-prefetchable,disabled)
  IRQ: 30 (4525840 events)
  Module Alias: "pci:v000010DEd000011C6sv00001569sd000011C6bc03sc00i00"
  Driver Info #0:
    Driver Status: nvidiafb is not active
    Driver Activation Cmd: "modprobe nvidiafb"
  Driver Info #1:
    Driver Status: nouveau is not active
    Driver Activation Cmd: "modprobe nouveau"
  Driver Info #2:
    Driver Status: nvidia_384_drm is not active
    Driver Activation Cmd: "modprobe nvidia_384_drm"
  Driver Info #3:
    Driver Status: nvidia_384 is not active
    Driver Activation Cmd: "modprobe nvidia_384"
  Config Status: cfg=new, avail=yes, need=no, active=unknown
  Attached to: #19 (PCI bridge)

Primary display adapter: #33
```

Comment: File a bug report or feature request

Comment: or maybe there is a way to download and save that file to where it is expected to be...

Comment: I don't see how this is offtopic - upgrading Ubuntu from 17.04 to 17.10 introduced the regression.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you're using the graphics PPA verify you forced their version of packages.  I had a similar problem after 17.10 upgrade.  Run vulkaninfo to verify your loader is 'good'.

PPA:
https://launchpad.net/~graphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa

Your /usr/share/vulkan/icd.d/nvidia_icd.json should look something like this:

```
{
    "file_format_version" : "1.0.0",
    "ICD": {
        "library_path": "libGLX_nvidia.so.0",
        "api_version" : "1.0.49"
    }
}
```

You likely have one that looks like this given your output:

```
{
    "file_format_version" : "1.0.0",
    "ICD": {
        "library_path": "libGL.so.1",
        "api_version" : "1.0.49"
    }
}
```

Comment: That seems to be the problem indeed. How would I fix that?

Comment: Assuming it's just the ICD library path issue you could edit the JSON file as shown.  Barring that use the drivers at the PPA linked above.

Comment: And the file won't be overwritten somehow by an update? In any case, I did just that and it fixed it.

Comment: Like explained here  I replaced "library_path": "libGL.so.1" by "library_path": "libGLX_nvidia.so.0" in the file /usr/share/vulkan/icd.d/nvidia_icd.json and it works. Thank you.

Comment: With these changes I get "ERROR: [Loader Message] Code 0 : libGLX_nvidia.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory" when trying to run vulkaninfo. This is using nvidia-418 and locate returns results on the library. Any ideas on what could be the issue?